# Gitlab-runner pass custom options to docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to pass custom options to the docker:
I'm looking for a way to pass `--cgroup-parent` option to docker from `gitlab-runner`.

Or at least these 2 options , `--cpuset-mems=""`, `--cpuset-cpus=""`

On the official gitlab-runner site I did not find any info about passing any of these or any custom options to the docker.

Comment: based on this issue you cant set cgroup yet: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28644

Answer (score 0):

It is here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runnersdocker-section

You need to create a `[runners.docker]` section.

As it says, the file to be edited can be found in:

```
/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml on *nix systems when gitlab-runner is
executed as root (this is also path for service configuration)

~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml on *nix systems when gitlab-runner is
executed as non-root

./config.toml on other systems
```

Comment: There is no option to pass --cgroup-parent option to the docker (Of course I've checked docs first). Unfortunately, there is no option to pass any custom option. I have to write my own controller to be able to control dockers as I want.